# Restkit seed core-data with objects from a local file on launch

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, restkit, restkit-0.20

I'm working on an app, in which I need to seed core-data with some local data stored in a file and I'm using Restkit.

Right now, I have stored the data in JSON format in a text file, and on launch I use the "RKManagedObjectImporter" to map the JSON to objects. Since the data is huge, it takes a lot of time (at least 30 seconds) just to map the data from JSON to Core-data objects.

I obviously cannot make the user wait 30 seconds on the first launch, and the data is required as soon as the app launches. So what alternative do I have here ? Is there a way to create mapped objects and store them in a file ?

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a Core Data .sqlite file and distribute it with the app instead of a JSON file. Then, when the app launches you can check if the user has an existing store file and, if not, copy the default file from the bundle into the desired location.

RestKit also offers importing support using a .sqlite source file, see [here](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/blob/development/Examples/RKTwitterCoreData/Classes/RKTwitterAppDelegate.m).

Comment: Thank you so much!! I found the sqlite file in the documents directory and I copied it and loaded data from it. Worked like a charm :)